# PHP Converting DateInterval to int

Tags: php, date, datetime, dateinterval, date-math

I'm using this code:

```
$due_date = new DateTime($_POST['due_date']);

$today = new DateTime();
$months = $due_date->diff($today);

$months->format("%m");

$fine = 0.02 * $price * $months; // i got error in this line

$bill = $price + $fine;
```

I want to calculate, if someone is late to pay then they will be fined per month. And the error message is:

```
Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int
```

Comment: You never do something with the return value of [`$months->format("%m");`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php).

Comment: `$months` is a Datetime object here is a sample one... `DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 4
    [d] => 12
    [h] => 6
    [i] => 56
    [s] => 9
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 133
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message appears because `$months` is not an int, but a Datetime object like this one:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 4
    [d] => 12
    [h] => 6
    [i] => 56
    [s] => 9
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 133
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

You can get the integer value of months like this

```
$due_date = new DateTime('13-02-2016');

$today = new DateTime();
$months = $due_date->diff($today);

echo $months->m;
```

Check the above result in [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5bea753c457fe44d80aa13148e7660c51ebd84bc)

So basically your code will look like

```
$due_date = new DateTime($_POST['due_date']);

$today = new DateTime();
$months = $due_date->diff($today);

$fine = 0.02 * $price * $months->m; // i got no error in this line

$bill = $price + $fine;
```

Comment: @Pevara thanks, `format` it was not needed in this answer

Answer (score 2):

You calculate the difference in months, but you never actually use that value. The `format` method outputs something, but doesn't change the actual DateInterval.

Try it like this:

```
$due_date = new DateTime($_POST['due_date']);

$today = new DateTime();
$diff = $due_date->diff($today);

$months = $diff->format("%m");

$fine = 0.02 * $price * $months;

$bill = $price + $fine;
```

Comment: `$months  = $due_date->diff($today)->format("%m"));`

Comment: @splash58 Sure, or `$months = (new DateTime($_POST['due_date']))->diff(new DateTime())->format("%m");`... I was just trying to point out the `diff`erence ;)

Comment: If it doesn't work in your version of php (< 5.4), you probably shouldn't be using it anymore..

Answer (score 2):

Peter Darmis's answer is wrong. I can't downvote nor comment it so I will add this new answer.

DateInterval represents a period of time by deconstructing the interval in different parts, years, months, days etc... So "m" in the proposed solution will never be bigger than 12.

So you should probably do something like this:

```
$due_date = new DateTime('13-02-2016');

$today = new DateTime();
$diff = $due_date->diff($today);

$months = ($diff->y * 12) + $diff->m;

echo $months;
```

Check it in the sandbox:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/907b39ffee4586c4c9481ff3e0ea1aeb2d27c7b8